# How to store and reuse schema within different collections in Postman?

Tags: json, testing, automated-tests, schema, postman

I'm working on Postman testing and I want to validate the schema against the response. The schema is applicable to a lot of different collections in the work-space and so I would want to store it in a separate file and reuse.

**Is there a way** to reference that file within the collection and extract that file along with when the collection is exported.

- For example: *example.postman_collection.json* would also contain the referenced file.
- From my [research](https://blog.getpostman.com/2018/04/11/looping-through-a-data-file-in-the-postman-collection-runner/) so far, I have found that files can be imported at the time the collection is run which is not what I'm looking for. I don't want any external dependencies.

**If not**, what would be the other way to handle this in Postman and reuse the schema within different collections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason you want to store it as a file? 
You can store schema as a global or environmental variable and they can be easily accessed.

```
//Var for schema
const customerSchema = {
  "required": ["id"],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 100,
      "maximum": 1000
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 25
    }
  }
};

//Store it as environmental variable (or global).
pm.environment.set("customerSchema", customerSchema);

//Get it from environmental variable (or global).
var expectedSchema = pm.environment.get("customerSchema");

//validate
pm.test('Customer schema is matching expected result', function() {
     pm.expect(tv4.validate(responseBody, expectedSchema)).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: Currently I'm storing the schema as a variable the same way you described. But I want it's scope to extend to other collections as well. It's a schema shared by several collections.

Comment: You can use the same environment for multiple collections. I understand that's not the answer you're looking for. Just saying.

Comment: Absolutely agree! That's the last resort I'm planning on using, since it would introduce ordering dependency among the collections. The one containing schema would always need to be run first. But, thanks for looking into it!